# Как без перезагрузки страницы перейти по другому url

Tags: python, html, django, ajax

У меня есть чат. За отображение списка чатов и контента чата отвечает один view:

```
def chats_view(request, chat_uuid=None):
    if chat_uuid:
            context = {
                # Переменные и для отображения списка, и для отображения контента чата
                }
            return render(request, 'chats/chats.html', context)
    else:
        context = {
            # Переменные для отображения только списка чатов
            }
        return render(request, 'chats/chats.html', context)
```

На url "/chats/" только список чатов, а на url "/chats/<chat_uuid>/" уже и список чатов и контент выбранного чата. При нажатии на любой чат без перезагрузки страницы рядом должно появиться окно с контентом чата и поменяться url с "/chats/" на "/chats/<chat_uuid выбранного чата>". Я пробовал сделать это через ajax, но в html контента есть шаблонные теги django и они рендерятся как текст.

Comment: Вероятно, при обновлении ajax, если вы используете jquery, надо использовать `$(elem).html(chat) `вместо `$(elem).text(chat)` , или использовать фильтр safe `{{ content|safe }}` в шаблоне.

Добавьте больше кода для понимания ситуации.

Comment: Так же, нельзя просто так взять и обновить window.location, можно использовать для таких целей анкор, наример `/chat#uuid`,  и в js по нему запросить контент чата.

Comment: Ещё я стараюсь избегать передачи html через ajax, дело вкуса конечно, я бы вернул по uuid (или его отсутсвию) массив доступных каналов.. А контент чата уже вторая история, сокеты там всякие, воркеры, брокеры сообщений..

Comment: Так же не совсем понятна формулировка "появится окно". windows.open(url_with_uid,'_blank'), или в элеметне текущего окна...

Comment: я и испольую $(elem).html(chat) но всякие {% if %} {% endif %} просто в ковычки помещаются и отображаются как текст. Просто рядом должно появиться окно, как у VK например в пк версии сайта